# WPF: Change the CornerRadius for only the last item in a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a `ListBox` with round corners. I've also added a bottom border to all `ListBoxItem`s except for the last one.

The `ListBoxItem`s, however, have normal, square corners, so when hovering over or selecting the first or last items, you can see an overlap between the round `ListBox` corner and the square `ListBoxItem` corners.

[image: ListBox CoprnerRadius Mismatch]

I can't set CornerRadius the same way I set BorderThickness - I think that's because CornerRadius is a property of the Border property(?).

I can force ALL `ListBoxItem`s to have all round corners which fixes the overlap, but then ALL `ListBoxItem`s have round underlines & selections- which I'd rather not have.  I only want those round corners on the bottom of the last item (and eventually top of the first item)

I would like to use a similar sort of trigger for setting `CornerRadius` that I do for setting `BrushThickness`.

Is there a way to set the corner radius of just the last item in a `ListBox`? (and eventually the first item)

In my test, I'm using the MaterialDesignTheme package from NuGet. Because that's non-standard, I'll add all my code here (also note: I'm new to WPF, so feel free to critique anything that looks off):

App.xaml:

```
<Application . . .
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <materialDesign:BundledTheme BaseTheme="Light" PrimaryColor="DeepPurple" SecondaryColor="Lime" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml: (Note, if you uncomment the commented section, it styles all `ListBoxItems` like I would want only the last `ListBoxItem` styled)

```
<Window . . .
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
        TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
        TextElement.FontSize="13"
        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" 
        TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"        
        Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
        FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IsLastItemInContainerConverter x:Key="IsLastItemInContainerConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
            <ListBox x:Name="GameListBox" 
                     BorderBrush="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}" 
                     BorderThickness="1">
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignListBoxItem}">
                        <!--<Style.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 0 10 10"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Style.Resources>-->
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                   Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 1" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignDivider}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>

                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                   Converter={StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock>  Plain
                    </TextBlock>
                </ListBoxItem>

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock>  Old
                    </TextBlock>
                </ListBoxItem>

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock>  ListBox
                    </TextBlock>
                </ListBoxItem>

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <TextBlock>  Full of junk
                    </TextBlock>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

...and in MainWindow.xaml.cs, I have defined the converter to find the last item:

```
    public class IsLastItemInContainerConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)value;
            ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

            return ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item)
                    == ic.Items.Count - 1;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                                  object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would try an opacity mask and clip the whole control. A listbox has a border round it so I would think you could adapt this approach: https://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/wpf-easy-rounded-corners-for-anything/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, please understand that the `MaterialDesignTheme` package was not used in my code.

### Items.cs

Instead of using `Converter`, I added a model class.

```
 public class Items
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsFirst { get; set; }
        public bool IsLast { get; set; }
    }
```

### App.xaml

I defined styles of `ListBoxItem`, `ListBox` like below.

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="listboxitem">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="border"
                                Background="White"
                                BorderBrush="#AAAAAA"
                                BorderThickness="1 1 1 0"
                                CornerRadius="0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Normal" 
                                       Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFirst}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="10 10 0 0"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLast}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0 0 10 10"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 1 1"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#666666"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#666666"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" x:Key="listbox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource listboxitem}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                        <Border Background="Transparent"
                                BorderBrush="#AAAAAA"
                                BorderThickness="0 0 0 0"
                                CornerRadius="10">
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

### MainWindow.xaml

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lbx" Style="{StaticResource listbox}"/>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lbx.ItemsSource = GetItems();
        }

        private List<Items> GetItems()
        {
            List<Items> source = new List<Items>();
            source.Add(new Items { Name = "Plain", IsFirst = true });
            source.Add(new Items { Name = "Old" });
            source.Add(new Items { Name = "ListBox" });
            source.Add(new Items { Name = "Full of junk", IsLast = true }); ;

            return source;
        }
    }
```

It will be shown like this..

[image: result]

Comment: this does work but requires you to modify the model to include is first and last properties,
there should probably be a better way.

Comment: @AthulRaj If you can't change the model, you'll have to find another way, but this method looks natural and good. Also, it is difficult to handle basically because you have to adjust the CornerRadius at the top and bottom of the ListBox and even fill it when it is in Selection state. Therefore, it would be better for using Trigger to handle it simply through the model properties.

Comment: Natural and good? This is a listbox. What happens when there are 10 items in that space instead of 4 so you have to scroll?

Comment: @Andy Yes, It is ListBox. However, it is often used like RadioButton.

Comment: As you said, if you need to Scroll, you should fix the CornerRadius at the top and bottom of the ItemsPresenter on the Template of the ListBox. But if you do so, there is a problem with the Fill of the ListBoxItem.